# SimpleModal Error box, Overlapping Form?

Tags: simplemodal

http://tinyurl.com/6ekkq8y

The error box keeps overlapping the form (press submit), or underlapping i should perhaps say. I've tried adding clear floats to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.contact-message` div that contains `.contact-error` has a (inline) fixed height of 30px. If you remove that the error will push down the form rather than underlap.

Comment: Ah thanks, i've increased it, but it means i've had to increase the height of the div it's contained in which makes is fine for when there's lots of error messages but when there's none, it leaves a lot of whitespace down the bottom (code tags don't seem to work?)

// dynamically determine height
   var h = 500;
   if ($('#contact-subject').length) {
    h += 26;
   }
   if ($('#contact-cc').length) {
    h += 22;
   }